# How do I run docker-compose up on a a docker-swarm?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

I'm new to Docker and trying to get started by deploying locally a hello-world Flask app on Docker-Swarm.

So far I have my Flask app, a Dockerfile, and a docker-compose.yml file.

```
version: "3"
services:
  webapp:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
```

`docker-compose up` works fine and deploys my Flask app.

I have started a Docker Swarm with `docker swarm init`, which I understand created a swarm with a single node:

```
ID                           HOSTNAME  STATUS  AVAILABILITY  MANAGER STATUS
efcs0tef4eny6472eiffiugqp *  moby      Ready   Active        Leader
```

Now, I don't want workers or anything else, just a single node (the manager node created by default), and deploy my image there.

Looking at these instructions https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part4/#create-a-cluster it seems like I have to create a VM driver, then scp my files there, and ssh to run docker-compose up. Is that the normal way of working? Why do I need a VM? Can't I just run docker-compose up on the swarm manager? I didn't find a way to do so, so I'm guessing I'm missing something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Running `docker-compose up` will create individual containers directly on the host.

With swarm mode, all the commands to manage containers have shifted to `docker stack` and `docker service` which manage containers across multiple hosts. The `docker stack deploy` command accepts a compose file with the `-c` arg, so you would run the following on a manager node:

```
docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yml stack_name
```

to create a stack named "stack_name" based on the version 3 yml file. This command works the same regardless of whether you have one node or a large cluster managed by your swarm.

Comment: Thanks! I think that answers my question, although doesn't work with my current docker-compose file because it seems the build option is not supported and it needs a link to a pre-built image on a repository. I'll fix those and post back :)

Comment: The compose file used by swarm doesn't have many of the docker-compose extensions. I've been using `docker-compose config` (from memory, command may be a bit off) to preprocess the yml into one that swarm can use. And you can still use docker-compose for the build, push, and pull steps.

Comment: Creating an image and pushing to my repository (local images don't seem to work) worked! Also thanks for the `docker-compose config` hint! Very useful.

Comment: @zapatilla Can you please provide more details on how you were able to use `docker-compose config` command to pre-process the yml